# SQL Server & ODBC with C Language

Tags: c, sql-server, odbc, bulkinsert

I find that when doing bulk operations (like bulk update, delete, insert etc.) ODBC routines mimick the operation by iterating thru the array of data given in the program, since SQL Server does not have bulk operation facilities. I am worried about the performance, if it goes for a single record processing.

Right now I am using C & ODBC for SQL Server. Is there any other better approach to speed up the process and accomplish what I want. There are about 200+ programs that do tremendous bulk data operations.

If C & ODBC is Not the right thing, then can you advise me on what would be the best tool to do that. Somebody I knew suggested that using SSIS instead of C-ODBC would improve performance. Someone Advise on the right approach please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my past experience...and I have no way to quantify this for you....ODBC + C is going to be the most performant solution in terms of accessing SQL Server. It is the fastest, most direct way of getting data in and out of SQL Server. However, it's up to you to optimize your code for doing this.

All of the benchmark software I've ever used for SQL Server, and this includes the TPC-C benchmarks, used a combination of ODBC and C for accessing the server for the lowest possible latency, but the code was complicated.